# Factoring RSA primes, p and q, given n, e and d. SageMath implementation. I am receiving an error

Tags: python, rsa

```
n=3046489427752548614835705731738608655336037381904612690933920645578584306854679988103697087282316860957470393164677006321152198903148509969091675769600609

e=65537

d=2423357597198465971720020922639076344965108271563411031993639487546008469794786697722604241075597290450041126457953384566271052978353705415054748363082433

b = e * d - 1

print(b) # b sayısının ilk halini görmek için

while (b % 2 == 0):
    b = b /2
else:
    t = b
    print(t) # b 2'ye sürekli olarak bölündü ve bölünemeyen kısmı da t olarak kaldı.

a = 2
while (a < n):
    x = power_mod(a, t, n) - 1
    d = gcd (x,n)
    a += 1
    if (factorial(d) == 1) and (factorial(d) == n):
        p = d
        q = n // d
        break
print(p)
print(q)
```

Here is my code, above. I need to factor n into primes p and q. However, SageMath giving me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-d05a9147cce3> in <module>
     17 a = Integer(2)
     18 while (a < n):
---> 19     x = power_mod(a, t, n) - Integer(1)
     20     d = gcd (x,n)
     21     a += Integer(1)
/ext/sage/sage-9.2/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sage/arith/misc.py in power_mod(a, n, m)
   2200 
   2201     apow = a % m
-> 2202     while n&1 == 0:
   2203         apow = (apow*apow) % m
   2204         n = n >> 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'sage.rings.rational.Rational' and 'int'
```

What might be the problem? This is my first program. I am going insane.

I have edited some parts after my professor made a comment.

```
    if (d != 1) and (d != n):
```

Here, I thought "!" was factorial. Even though I fixed it, nothing has changed. I am receiving the same error.

Comment: Please try, if you get the same error, if you replace `b = b /2` by `b = b //2`. Sure, numerically it should always be an integer, but maybe it gets the typing wrong.

Comment: I did what you said, the error went missing but I cannot print p and q... :( I do not understand why. The algorithm should have worked.

Comment: This appears to be more or less an implementation of the algorithm mentioned in 8.2.2(i) of Menezes et. al. "Handbook of Applied Cryptography". However, this line in your code `if (factorial(d) == 1) and (factorial(d) == n):` doesn't make sense in that context, really nor in any context that I can think of. It looks wrong.

Comment: You are right, I have changed that part as follows.  if (d != 1) and (d != n):

Comment: You haven't corrected implemented the algorithm. I suggest you re-read the algorithm carefully.

Answer (score 2):

It is due to the fact that `b` is not an integer but a rational number. Even though `b / 2` outputs a number with a nil fractional part, it is still considered as a rational (like 1.0 instead of 1). Fast modular exponentiation cannot deal with rational numbers, hence the error.

I tried your code and got the same error as you. I solved it by performing a division over integers when computing `b`, like this:

```python
while (b % 2 == 0):
    b = b // 2
```

Note that `print(t)` fools you by making you believe that `t` is an integer, while it is actually a rational. You can print `type(t)` to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed the problem. I submitted my assignment. Here is the final code. It works perfectly well.

```
b = e * d - 1
while (b % 2 == 0):
    b = b /2
else:
    t = int(b)
a = 2
while (a < n):
    x = power_mod(a, t, n) - 1
    d = gcd (x,n)
    a += 1
    if (d != 1) and (d != n):
        p = d
        q = n // d
        print(d)
        print(n // d)
        break
```